# Visual SourceSafe Installation

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I have been given a task to:

```
1. Install Visual Source Safe.
2. Configure it into my local system
3. Make 2 user’s on it else Admin.
```

The thing is when i download the installer and run it. This error Logs:

The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing.

Please tell me what is wrong and what should i do to properly start it

Comment: You might get better results over here: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks @aradil . You mean i should post my question at the link you provided ??

Comment: Yup, that's what I'd do.

Comment: Posted their and got (- negative) marks :-( @aradil

Comment: Odd, I couldn't find your post there at all. Did you remove it?

Comment: Some one closed it. [Click here for the LINK](http://serverfault.com/questions/681040/installation-of-visual-source-safe)

Comment: Thanx brother, i am now using GITHUB. :-) I appreciate  your participation

Comment: No problem; also I know a number of people who have used source safe and hated it. You may be dodging a bullet.

Comment: Additionally, they closed your question and told you to put it in superuser.com, rather than serverfault.com. I personally disagree with that opinion; they said you were posting a question that wasn't business related and was just for an end-user. Clearly, if you wanted to install it on multiple boxes this is for a business use case, and not just an end user. Oh well. I don't have the reputation over there yet to do anything about it haha.